# What is the source location from where the npm install command downloads the required packages?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to get the source location (URL) to which the command npm install is trying to connect and get the dependent packages to be downloaded, based on the package.json file and place it in the local box.

From the below mentioned url: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_npm.htm ,I came to know that it is trying to connect https://nodejs.org/en/

Can anyone tell me whether the above is correct or is there any other url that it is trying to connect and download the packages.

We have an environment that is restricted from internet access. In order to access few urls, I need to raise a request to allow access to certain urls  based on the proxy rules.

Answer (score 5):

**registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"**

This info can be found in the npm config.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Can you please confirm my understanding like if I add the above URL to the whitelist for proxy rule setup in the system, then it will be work for me.I can run the npm install and it will download all the packages.

Comment: Since the system is not having access to internet my Admin team asked me to provide the url which they can include in the proxy rule whitelist based on which it the url can be accessible. Hence I am trying my best to provide the url so that npm install works for me.