# how npm connects to repository and downloads the components?

Tags: node.js, npm, repository, npm-install

I am newbie to nodejs/npm , right now wanted to install few components like bower/gulp in my lab . I am restricted by enterprise firewall , as the lab is highly secured without any access to internet. I am thinking of the following option to proceed with lab poc without causing much changes to the existing technical infrastructure.

Option:
Provide white listed urls to firewall team which npm will connect to - to download the components.

Now I am not clear what urls do I need to white list in firewall for proper functioning of npm component installations ?

Can someone help me with the list of urls for the above scenario?

Thanks for the help

Comment: You can try with this url

npm install --save https://github.com/Amitesh/gulp-rev-all/tarball/master

Comment: so this will install the component locally right , so github.com is one of the url which needs to be whitelisted in firewall right ? Any other url ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, I would start the npm installation in verbose mode, and figure out which URLs are being accessed or attempted, and then open up access to those sites in the firewall. For example:

```
bash-4.1$ npm install foo --verbose 2> verbose.log
bash-4.1$ grep "http" verbose.log
npm verb addNameTag registry:https://registry.npmjs.org/foo not in flight; fetching
npm verb request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/foo
npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/foo
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/foo
npm verb etag https://registry.npmjs.org/foo from cache
bash-4.1$
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"

This info can be found in the npm config.
[What is the source location from where the npm install command downloads the required packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675756/what-is-the-source-location-from-where-the-npm-install-command-downloads-the-req)